# Is it possible to adjust the eviction policy in AWS ElasticCache - Redis to be less than 100%?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, elastic-cache

Currently, the policy only executes when it reaches 100%, which often results in OutOfMemory errors.
It would seem logical to have the ability to set the policy to be executed at, say, 90% of memory used.

Alternatively, could there be a way to manually trigger the eviction policy through code, for instance, when  CloudWatch Alarm is set off due to memory usage exceeding a certain limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to AWS ElasticCache engineer, I got these answers:

1. Currently there is no way to set the Eviction to be at other than 100% percent.
2. Even if we've reached the 100% mark, once the Eviction started, there is no blockage on the DB. We can continue working as usual.
3. The Eviction is being performed on all documents with TTL set, regardless of how much time left (It tries to free the shortest TTL first, but there are no guarantees).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about OOM due to memory usage reaching 100%, you could consider lowering the max_memory setting from its current value. Additionally, there are various strategies you could adopt, such as setting shorter TTLs or utilizing reserved memory for backups without actually performing backups.

Please excuse any clumsiness in my response as this is my first time answering.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).